# Make attributes mandatory for Groovy Class

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy class and want to make sure that certain attributes are always set in the constructor.

Is there any way to way to make attributes mandatory in a Groovy class?

Thanks

Comment: You mean other than checking they have been set in the constructor itself? There's [GContracts](http://gcontracts.org/) if that's what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You could use @TupleConstructor with specific attribute force :

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

@TupleConstructor(force=true)
    class Car {
        String brand
        List options
        private boolean sold = false

        // constructor
        Car(boolean sold) {
            this.sold = sold
        }

        boolean hasBeenSold() { sold }
    }
}

car = new Car(true)
assert car.hasBeenSold
```

[More info](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/index.html?groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html)